# Export to PNG image from mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am trying to export mxGraph to PNG image. Graph vertex label texts contain html formatting. In the exported image, only html tags are displayed instead of formatted text.

This is for javascript as client and C# as backend

[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxCpH.png) [Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80s72.png)

```
// Setting HTML Label to true

mxGraph.prototype.isHtmlLabel = function(cell)
{
    return true;
}

graph.convertValueToString = function(cell)
{
    if (mxUtils.isNode(cell.value))
    {
        var labelVal = cell.getAttribute('label', '');

        if (labelVal != null)
        {
            return labelVal;
        }

        return '';
    }

    return '';
};

var tmpElem = doc.createElement("testnode");
// Setting label text as HTML formatted content
tmpElem.setAttribute('label', '<div class="roottitle">Label Text</div>');
graphItm = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, tmpElem, 0, 0, 100, 30);

var ExportGraphToImage = function()
{
    exportFile("png");
}

function exportFile(format) {
    var bg = '#ffffff';
    var scale = 1;
    var b = 1;
    var imgExport = new mxImageExport();
    var bounds = graph.getGraphBounds();
    var vs = graph.view.scale;
    // New image export
    var xmlDoc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
    var root = xmlDoc.createElement('output');
    xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
    // Renders graph. Offset will be multiplied with state's scale when painting state.
    var xmlCanvas = new mxXmlCanvas2D(root);
    xmlCanvas.translate(Math.floor((b / scale - bounds.x) / vs), Math.floor((b / scale - bounds.y) / vs));
    xmlCanvas.scale(scale / vs);
    imgExport.drawState(graph.getView().getState(graph.model.root), xmlCanvas);
    // Puts request data together
    var w = Math.ceil(bounds.width * scale / vs + 2 * b);
    var h = Math.ceil(bounds.height * scale / vs + 2 * b);
    var xml = mxUtils.getXml(root);
    if (bg != null) {
        bg = '&bg=' + bg;
    }
    new mxXmlRequest('../mxGraph/Export.ashx', 'filename=export.' + format + '&format=' + format +
        bg + '&w=' + w + '&h=' + h + '&xml=' + encodeURIComponent(xml)).
        simulate(document, '_blank');
}
```

Formatted labels for vertex is expected in the exported image. Instead, labels with actual HTML content is displayed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mxGraph - Export to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377771/mxgraph-export-to-image)